# array of buffers in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm attempting to implement an array of buffers in Verilog where data will ripple through the buffers upon a positive edge of a clock signal (CLK) while an input signal (`data_valid`) is active. However, I'm encountering a problem where my `data_in` wire isn't connecting to the first buffer, resulting in my output being stuck in a high-impedance state.

```
module convolution_ip(input [7:0] data_in, 
                      input reset, input wire init_valid,  clk, 
                       output [9:0] final_output );
                       
    integer j ;
    reg [7:0] input_fm_buff[24:0] ;
    wire input_load;  

    /////////////////////////////////////////
    assign input_load = clk & init_valid;
    /////////////////////////////////////////

    always@(posedge input_load or posedge reset)begin
     if (reset) begin
            // Reset buffer
            for (int j = 0; j <=24; j = j + 1) begin
                input_fm_buff[j] <= 8'h00;
            end
        end else begin
            for (int j = 0; j<=24; j = j+1) begin
               if (j==24)begin  input_fm_buff[j] <= data_in;
               end  
                input_fm_buff[j] <= input_fm_buff[j+1];
            end  
           end
    end
    assign final_output = input_fm_buff[1];
endmodule
```

schematic is looking like this
[image: Schematics]

I tried for loop and nonblocking assignments to synchronize the data flow through each buffer. I want the data to ripple through the buffers when `init_valid` is `HIGH` and there is a positive edge of a `clk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues here (apart from your question):

1. You should use `posedge input_load` in sensitivity list because this way you are trying to feed clock to your logic via an `AND` gate. It is not recommended in FPGA because clock routes are different than the data routes i.e. clock signal travels on separate dedicates routes. With the `AND` gate you are bringing the `CLK` signal on to normal data routes. So the simple solution is you should use an extra `else if` in the always block.
2. Your output should be 8-bit i.e. `output [7:0] final_output` but you have defined it as 10-bit.

Now, to the main issue of as to why `data_in` wire isn't connecting to the first buffer? You have defined your logic in the else block, as below, in a way that if `j==24` then the if statement is correct and your value get assigned to the buffer address 24 i.e. `input_fm_buff[24] <= data_i`. But then, followed by the if statement, you are reassigning a new value to `input_fm_buff[j]` outside the if statement and that happens to be `input_fm_buff[j+1]`, i.e. 25, which is a non-existing memory.

In other words, when `j==24` then both the statements `input_fm_buff[j] <= data_in;` and `input_fm_buff[j] <= input_fm_buff[j+1];` are executed, resulting in the implementation of later i.e. `input_fm_buff[j] <= input_fm_buff[j+1];`.

```
if (j==24)begin  
    input_fm_buff[j] <= data_in;
end  
    input_fm_buff[j] <= input_fm_buff[j+1];
```

The solution is to wrap your logic in if else statement.

```
if (j==24)begin  
    input_fm_buff[j] <= data_in;
end  
else begin
    input_fm_buff[j] <= input_fm_buff[j+1];
end
```